# play free draw in fabricjs canvas. by serialize and deserialize

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I m working with fabricjs canvas to draw free drawing..
I want to do is record my drawing and play it.. means i draw on canvas.. and serialize it.. after that i want it to deserialize and  play it as it drawing..

something like this: 
http://ramkulkarni.com/temp/2012-10-03/
in this post of ramkulkarni there is thing but i can't implement it to my fabricjs canvas..
i visited fabricjs website for serialize but i cant found for play it...

also i want to save it as gif if possible..
but play is very important now... 
thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

The demo you provided records by buffering all draw commands with a time stamp. Then you can just serialize it with JSON.stringify. To play it back will require the same application or a player that understands the buffered commands. A pen stroke is just a set of mouse/pen/gesture points each with a time stamp.

The advantage of this method of recording is that the commands can be modified, ,different pens, different colours, scaled,rotation,translation, even into the 3rd dimension, when you play it back. Playback speed can be varied. It is light weight and the data it generates is small. It can be saved as you go and you can also use the recording as a drawing element, that can be nested recursively. Very handy for creating complex designs. One disadvantage is that is can be difficult if you do not have a command by command undo to reverse the play.

Another method is (as you hinted) is to encode the drawing as you go. GIF is not good as a general purpose recorder. It is memory hungry, it has a very limited pallet so you are forced to dither, or only use 256 colours per frame. Colour quantisation is slow (if you use it) and the results are medium at best. Oh and the alpha channel is one bit. GIF's are not for recording.

What I do is encode to WEBM as I draw. There are a few Javascript WEBM encoders on GItHub. They take as input the canvas 2D context or the raw image data. Encoding is fast enough to not interfere with your drawing (put the encoder on a web worker for best results) It can handle large canvas sizes and long drawing times. Best of all it is very portable. Everything can play a webm video and I personally like it as a video format.

A cut down webM encoder is under 250 lines of Javascript. At its heart the encoder uses the "webp" image format. `toDataURL` supports this so the hard work is mostly in the native call `.toDataURl("image/webp",quality);` then just wrap that in timing data and appropriate header and data specifiers.  It will pay to force the encoder to encode as you go rather than saving frame data until you call encode. It should be very easy to integrate with your Fabric.js app (just send it the imgData every time you want a frame captured) At the end encode and save (download/upload).

The down side with webM is that if your browser spits it (dam you Chrome), you lose the whole encoding (saving partial encoding is impractical). and recording pixel by pixel is to slow, so it is best you record frames at pen up. (I use a pixel odometer and a no action detection algorithm to grab frames) because the ctxs.getImageData is slow on large canvases and doing that as you are doing rapid drawing strokes is no good.

WebM encoding is the best if you wish to publish the recordings. A custom command records is best if it's only for inhouse/private use.

Comment: he is using fabricjs. FabricJs register freehand drawing like a series of path command in array. so he could just write a script that renders the path from command 0 to 1, then 0 to 2 and so on, reproducing the path creation. i will provide some code i manage to put down a draft

Comment: Using fabric??? or any framework, It really should not matter. The issue is whether or not the person doing the cording wants to publish or keep for posterity. Using a custom recorder will mean a very limited audience As technology changes so will the interface and thus there is a need to constantly rewrite, If you are using the canvas 2d context (even behind 10 frameworks) Use a webm encoder. Simple as `webEncoder.addFrame(ctx.getImageData(0,0,all,all)` No need to Interrogate the UI. Its just simple screen (canvas) capture.